# 250gsm stock good enough for cards?

Tags: board-game-adaptations

I'm creating my own version of risk and I'm now on to printing the cards.

My printer can use up to 250gsm paper, but before I purchase some I want to know if it will be suitable.

What is the standard for cards and card games?

Comment: In case you don't already know, there are printers online that will print a custom deck of cards using your graphics.  http://www.makeplayingcards.com/ is one such printer.  It appears that a single deck would cost around $15 depending on the card size.  Perhaps that service would give you a better quality result.  [Note: I haven't yet used this service.]

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, a standard playing card has a size of B8 and a weight of 1.8g. So if I got the math right, it's 180gsm.

Here is the link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck

Comment: yeah that definitely sounds right to me.